# emulator not working in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-emulator

Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_S'

```
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/kashminder/Documents/android dev/adt-bundle-linux/sdk//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: have you tried to remove the space in the path? It might be a problem... (also you should consider using some logic in your file structure. Why do you put the android sdk in a `Documents` folder? Why not in `/opt/` or some other logic path?)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html#troubleshooting. Is your system 64bit or 32 bit?. I also faced the same problem but solved it by installing ia32-libs package.

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the

```
  apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Next, install Java:

```
 apt-get install sun-java6-jdk.// install this if you have not done this before.
```

The link gives you an idea under the heading Troubleshooting Ubuntu.

Comment: i have installed java before.

Comment: did u try apt-get install ia32-libs